# Capturing keyboard input on a List View control, C++

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, input, keyboard

How do I capture key presses when a list view control has focus?

My window creation code looks like

```
// Window creation
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_APPWINDOW, g_szClassName, "Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 209, 351, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
HWND hwnd_list = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, "", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER  | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT, 1, 246, 201, 55, hwnd, (HMENU)IDL_LISTVIEW, hInstance, 0);
```

Inside `WndProc` I process the `WM_KEYPRESS` message and create a `MessageBox` displaying the virtual code, but its only triggering when I press keys after clicking outside the list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to take a look at control subclassing, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183%28VS.85%29.aspx.

If you're using MFC, it's a bit less painful. (Back in the day when Borland was still alive, it was a breeze in OWL, but that's ancient history.)

Comment: After reading the link, I added this to my code but it still isn't detecting keypresses.
http://pastebin.com/bgt319aa

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass the listview proc and then use 'WM_KEYDOWN' to capture the input.